# AES Encryption technique in objective C

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, aes

I am working on a project where i have to coordinate with .net team..
I need the equivalent code for the below mentioned AES encryption algorithm(written in C#) in objective -C..
I have tried using AESCrypt and CommonCrypt but its not woking well..getting different encryption value in both languages..

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

please help..thanks in advace

Comment: I spent about a week doing the same thing for my company.  I can't post code for that because it belongs to them, but you could look into `RNCryptor` and `NSData+Base64`.  Although the Base64 part is currently built into the latest versions of the apple languages.

Comment: There are many examples on the internet. I'm sure you'll find one. Also, what does this have to do with Caesar-Cipher?

Comment: Note that `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is `PBKDF2` as stated in msdn [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx). Apple's Common Crypto provides `PBKDF2`.

Comment: hello @zaph ,can i have code for PBKDF2 please..i tried using:CCKeyDerivationPBKDF but getting 0 as the key

Used this:
CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, myPassData.bytes, myPassData.length, salt.bytes, salt.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256, rounds, key1, 32);

Comment: @Putz1103 I tried encrypting my data using RNCryptor,but while decrypting the encrypted data using .net i get an exception of "The input data is not a complete block."

Answer (score 0):

In answer to using CCKeyDerivationPBKDF  in place of Rfc2898DeriveBytes:

A simple C example of PBKDF2 using Common Crypto.
Care should be taken in converting a C++ string to a byte array, typically use UTF-8 in the conversion.

```
const char  passwordData[] = "password";
size_t      passwordLength = strlen(passwordData);
uint8_t     salt[]         = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};
size_t      saltLength     = sizeof(salt);
uint        rounds         = 1000;
const int   derivedKeySize = 16;
uint8_t     derivedKey[derivedKeySize];

CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2,
                     passwordData, passwordLength,
                     salt, saltLength,
                     kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1,
                     rounds,
                     derivedKey, derivedKeySize);

for (int i=0; i<derivedKeySize; i++) {
    printf("%2x ", derivedKey[i]);
}
printf("%s", "\n");
```

Output

> 31 96 42 56 3f 7f b3 91 3e 85 fa 43 39 5e 69 93

Comment: Hello sir,can you please provide me the code for the above encryption techniques used in .net.I need its objective -C coding.
Using CCKeyDerivationPBKDF i was able to encrypt the key part,but i need to encrypt my data too along with key..
how will i do that?

Comment: Add what you have tried to the question. There are several Objective-C example on SO, you just need to adapt them to C++, that should be easy since Common Crypto is "C".